# Does the shovel do anything?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

We all know about tools like the **Woodcutter's Axe**, **Pickaxe**, and so on, but I'm wondering if the **Shovel** does anything. You find them all over the place, and you can pick them up, but they don't apparently have any use case.

You might dismiss this entirely, except that a non-player character (NPC) named **Bor** in the **Gloombound Mine** sometimes says to you:

> I'm here to mine, Outlander. So unless you want to dig, get out.

With that in mind, I get the feeling that the shovel has some sort of actual use. Of course, it's possible that **Bor** is simply saying that you might end up digging your own grave, if you don't get out of the way.

Side note: Shovel has value of **3** and a weight of **4**.

Comment: Please don't use code ticks when it isn't appropriate: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/using-code-ticks-for-technical-term-highlighting-considered-harmful

Comment: Modified post to avoid use of backticks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per the [Elder Scrolls Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Shovel_%28Skyrim%29):

> The Shovel is an item with no practical use.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are mods that allow it to perform certain functions.

Comment: @ChargingPun In what way does this not provide an answer?

Comment: Not that it doesn't answer the question, but rather that it doesn't say anything that hasn't been said by the other answer.